# How to set Windows 10 wallpaper using python scripting?

Tags: python

**Actually I am creating a Automatic Wallpaper changer in Python and I have created the function that fetches wallpapers using Unsplash API but the problem is I dnt knw that how to set that as a wallpaper and I think for setting wallpaper there is something that I have to change but I dnt knw what the main problem is I dnt knw how to set a wallpaper using python in windows 10. I am a beginner and I want your help I would be thankful to you if you help me.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, works in python3 on windows 10 for me

```
import os
import ctypes
path_user = os.path.expanduser('~')
print(path_user) # this print C:\Users\yourusername

name_of_file = 'test.png'
path_to_file = os.path.join(path_user, name_of_file)
print(path_to_file) # this print C:\Users\username\test.png
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path_to_file, 0)
```